product.info.options.wrapper cacheable false
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.options.wrapper" as="product_options_wrapper" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/wrapper.phtml">
                            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options" name="product.info.options" as="product_options" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options.phtml">
                                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\DefaultType" name="product.info.options.default" as="default" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/default.phtml"/>
                                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Text" name="product.info.options.text" as="text" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/text.phtml"/>
                                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\File" name="product.info.options.file" as="file" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/file.phtml"/>
                                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select" name="product.info.options.select" as="select" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/select.phtml"/>
                                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Date" name="product.info.options.date" as="date" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/date.phtml"/>
                            </block>
                            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Calendar" name="html_calendar" as="html_calendar" template="Magento_Theme::js/calendar.phtml"/>
                        </block>

Here is the code from the vendor's catalog_product_view.xml file. I need to set this block as cacheable false. The reason for this change is that when this page is visited multiple times by users, its version gets stored in the cache, and the page does not load completely. When the page is hard reloaded, it works correctly. Any ideas on how to override this and make it cacheable false?

You just need to add cacheable="false" to the block you need
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.options.wrapper" as="product_options_wrapper" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/wrapper.phtml" cacheable="false">
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options" name="product.info.options" as="product_options" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options.phtml">
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\DefaultType" name="product.info.options.default" as="default" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/default.phtml"/>
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Text" name="product.info.options.text" as="text" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/text.phtml"/>
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\File" name="product.info.options.file" as="file" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/file.phtml"/>
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select" name="product.info.options.select" as="select" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/select.phtml"/>
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Date" name="product.info.options.date" as="date" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/date.phtml"/>
</block>
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Calendar" name="html_calendar" as="html_calendar" template="Magento_Theme::js/calendar.phtml"/>

But this may not fix your problem, as this is not a good practice on main pages. (You can disable cache on pages like wishlist as it's a specific page for customer)
Every time a client visits this page, the server may be overloaded, impacting the performance of the whole site.
You must check the main source of your problem.
EDIT 1
To create a custom theme you need to create thoses files in app/design/frontend/<vendor_name>/<themeName|default>:
More infos about theme structure here
theme.xml:
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
<title>Store theme name</title>
<parent>Magento/luma</parent>

registration.php:
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

use \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::THEME, 'frontend/<vendor_name>/<themeName|default>', __DIR__);

app/design/frontend/<vendor_name>/<themeName|default>/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml
catalog_product_view.xml:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.options.wrapper" cacheable="false"/>
    </body>
</page>

Once you've created thoses files you have to flush the cache
To clear the pub/static directory:
rm -r <magento_root>/pub/static/*/*

To clear the var/view_preprocessed directory:
rm -r <magento_root>/var/view_preprocessed/*

apply the theme for your storefront in :
Content > Configuration > your website > Applied theme
Here you can select your newly created theme (Store theme name).
Save config and flush cache

I can't edit the core file . How i can achieve this in the custom theme . That was the actual question

Ho yeah mb, let me edit the answer to fit your need
